# Will the Blackrock Mountain Adventure in Hearthstone be free over time?

Tags: hearthstone

I was reading the patch notes for Hearthstone and found this:

"Five unique wings await those brave enough to delve into Blackrock Mountain. Each of the five wings are immediately available to purchase with real money or gold, **with a new wing unlocking for players to enter each week over the course of April**."

Does this mean that overtime players will be able to purchase Blackrock Mountain wings or does this mean that Blackrock Mountain adventure will be free over time?

Answer (score 8):

No, the entire adventure will be paid for, either with cash or with in-game gold.  They will not give out the whole thing for free over time.

The unlock they are referring to is availability.  Each wing of the adventure will be unlocked (playable, presuming you paid for it) at a rate of one per week.  They did the same thing with the Naxxramas adventure.

Multiple sources (although I can't find a direct Blizzard quote at the moment) also state that the first wing will not be released free for the first week, as it was during the Naxxramas release.  So no freebies.

Comment: I recall reading actually confirmation that the first week *will not* be free. I'll see if I can find a source.

Comment: @Schism - looks like you're right, as I found a few sources that say that, edited in.

Answer (score 0):

Nope I don't think so. Since an alternate to real cash is in-game gold and people have been paying for it, It would be unfair for these people to free the adventure later.